Animated movie taking place in an old man's memories
There is some girl picking up the old man's notes on the floor and then we get to glimpse into his memories. He lost his father to suicide. The son was near his father's study when he shot himself.
He rides on a roller coaster as his younger self inside his own mind and he notices more and more of the tracks are disappearing. There is a snowglobe that his father damaged at one time.
Language: English, don't know the origin though.
Animation: It was in 3D and colour.
Year: Made in the 2000's.

Hi. Do you know the approximate year? The country\language? Was it short or long? Was it in color? 2D or 3D? Was there any dialogue?

Spoken language English, don't know the origin though. It was in 3D and colour. Made in the 2000's.

You're looking for Imaginaerum from 2012, though it's not exactly an animation film.

Imaginaerum tells the story of an elderly composer, Tom, who suffers from severe dementia. As he has had the disease for years and has regressed into childhood, he remembers practically nothing from his adult life. His music, friends, all his past including the memory of his daughter are a blur in his fragile mind. All he has left is the imagination of a ten year old boy. As he drifts away into coma, it seems impossible to get back what he has lost. Or is it? The film is a journey between two different dimensions. Tom travels through his imaginary world seeking answers and finding memories, while his daughter, Gem, tries to recover the bond she had once shared with her father in the real world.

Everything you mentioned is there. It features the music of Finnish band Nightwish. Here's the trailer:




@Shon No problem! Don't forget to click on the check mark next to the answer to resolve the question.
